# MFMessageComposeViewController:canSendText: returns true if no SIM present

Tags: ios

If I take the SIM out of my iPhone then call [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]  it returns true, but obviously the device is not capable of sending SMSs.

Is this a bug or known behavior of this function?

Given this behavior, is there a workaround to know if the SMS cannot be sent as there's no sim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the iPhone is running iOS 5+, you may have iMessage available. This would cause `canSendText` to return YES.

Comment: So there's no way of knowing if text is sendable specifically via SMS?

Comment: I'm not expert on the topic, but, given Apple's previous track record, I wouldn't be surprised if the method texts are sent is opaque to the developer. Some privacy thing.